# how do i upgrade from magento 1.9.4.0 to 1.9.4.1

Tags: magento-1.9.4.0, magento-1.9.4.1

how do i upgrade from magento 1.9.4.0 to 1.9.4.1.

Do i just use the Magento Connect Manager? Do I need to back up my DB as well as exisiting install to be safe?

Answer (score 4):

You have two options:

1) Apply all patches to your Magento 1.9.4.0 (and you'll be with the latest version).

2) Override manually all core files. 1.9.4.1 includes all patches.

There's a third option with Composer but isn't used by most of the stores on Magento1 so I guess you should choose between the first two options.

Remember to make a backup of code & Database before an upgrade.

Comment: is it possible to Magento 1.9.4.0 version upgrade in Mganeto2 using the composer?

Comment: @DhavalPatel, from M1 to M2 upgradation you need third party migration tool or you can manually create all your modules in Magento 2 fresh setup. 
If your project have not many modules intergrated then i suggest go with Fresh M2 setup & create all modules in M2.

Comment: OK thanks I will try it